# Powershell Script using for each to export only Valid AD Users to csv and suppress Users it cannot find in AD

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

Good day all, I'm trying to write a script that will check if a User is valid and export the results to a .csv file. I'm using the "for each"  and erroraction -silentlycontinue cmdlet to check a list of Users from a .csv file and then verify on the Microsoft Teams admin center if that is a Valid User.

The problem I'm having is if I add the "$errorActionpreference" cmdlet which suppresses errors (or Users Not Found on Screen) the results in the CSV File are empty, If I remove the $errorAction cmdlet (hashed out in the script below), then it works fine by exporting the valid Users BUT it spits out a lot of errors on the screen.

The scripts just need to suppress error messages for invalid Users, Move to the next User in the csv file, and finally export the results of the valid Users to another csv file.

```
$path = Read-Host -Prompt "`nEnter the path of .csv file:"
if (Test-Path -Path $path) { break }
Write-Host "Wrong file or path specified. Please enter the correct 
path to file!" -ForegroundColor Red
     
Write-Host "File has been located in the path specified!" - 
ForegroundColor Green
$CsvFilePath = Import-CSV -Path $path     

# $ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue"
   
     $results = foreach ($Users in $CsvFilePath) {
     $User = $Users.UserPrincipalName
     Get-CsOnlineUser $User | Select-Object  UserPri*, LineURI, 
     TeamsUpgradeE*,IsSipEnabled, Enterprise*, 
    @{l="AssignedPlan";e={$_.AssignedPlan 
     - join "; "}}, @{l="FeatureTypes";e={$_.FeatureTypes -join "; 
    "}}
     }
    # $ErrorActionPreference = "silentlycontinue
    
  #Export Results: Prompt for Path, If file does not exist, create it!#
  $resultspathfilelocation = Read-Host -Prompt "`nEnter file path 
  to export results of 
  the Post Checks: "
  $FileName = "$resultspathfilelocation"
    if(Get-Item -Path $FileName -ErrorAction Ignore){
      Write-Host "File found in directory specified!"
      }
     else{
      New-Item -Verbose $FileName -ItemType File
     }
   $results | Export-Csv $resultspathfilelocation
```

Comment: Why are you "pre-creating" the file?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, Thanks for responding.  I receive batches of Users in a CSV file. I need to check if these are valid Users or not. If the User does not exist (e.g. invalid domain or misspelled email address), then just suppress the error messages and only report on the successful Users. If possible, if there are invalid Users then export that too. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Use a `Try...Catch` along with `-ErrorAction Stop` construct around your query then just hande the Catch errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to ignore the errors, why not just handle them properly?

```
$Results = foreach ($Users in $CsvFilePath) {
    Try {
        $User = $Users.UserPrincipalName
        $ThisUser = Get-CsOnlineUser $User -ErrorAction Stop
    # Output as custom object
        [pscustomobject]@{UPN = $User
                    TeamsUpgradeEffectiveMode = $ThisUser.TeamsUpgradeEffectiveMode
                    IsSipEnabled = $ThisUser.IsSipEnabled
                    AssignedPlan = ($ThisUser.AssignedPlan -join "; ")
                    FeatureTypes = ($ThisUser.FeatureTypes -join "; ")
                    Error = ''}
    }
    Catch {
    # User not found or error, output object with blank fields except for error
        [pscustomobject]@{UPN = $User
                    TeamsUpgradeEffectiveMode = ''
                    IsSipEnabled = ''
                    AssignedPlan = ''
                    FeatureTypes = ''
                    Error = $_.Exception.Message}
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me. Thank you so much. So for the invalid UPN it reports in the CSV as UserID not found and for the valid User, it provides all the required information just as planned, All in one CSV file which is excellent. Thanks again :)